# How to write AVERAGEIFS for certain criteria through cell references, or to include all values if blank

Tags: excel

I am looking to write an AVERAGEIFS statement that includes a cell reference for quick access to sorted data. I have three drop downs that I am using to sort through data, and can get the code to work if all three drop downs are utilized. However, I also want to see all the data included (essentially bypassing one of the criteria) if I select a blank entry on the drop down. I thought of a way if I wanted to add a character like 1 by having "1*" inserted in front of every entry and inserted in that drop down, but I would rather not do that. Is there a better way?

Here are 2 images to help explain what I am trying to do.

***Criteria in teal are all filled out:***
[image]

***Attempting to leave one cell reference blank to include all possible entries:***
[image]

Thank you for your time,
Will

Comment: Please look at https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: A. Raza, what is unclear about this post?